# How to type を on QWERTY JIS keyboard?

Tags: discussion

I purchased a Japanese keyboard (QWERTY JIS) from a thrift shop in Sendai. I am eager to learn how to type quickly with it, but I cannot find the を key on the keyboard.

Where am I looking it over?

Comment: This is probably going to be moved to the meta section, but do you know romaji? If you know romaji you can type Japanese. That's how they type.

Comment: I do know romanji, and I have used it in conjunction with a non-Japanese keyboard for some time. However, I would like to keep away from romanji, and this keyboard layout appears to let me do that for the most part.  Does your comment mean that I will have to switch my keyboard layout to type this particular character?

Comment: I'm saying that even Japanese people use romaji for typing (note the spelling of romaji, btw). So if you want to type with kana because you want a challenge, I guess that's fine, but if you want to type the way Japanese people do, you can do so with the keyboard you already had. You just need an IME.

Comment: I would guess that the most frequent way that Japanese people enter their own language nowadays is via the ten key method rather than either romaji or kana keyboards.

Comment: `the ten key method` -- えっ、スマホじゃなくパソコンでそんなのできるの？

Answer (score 2):

It should be on the zero key above わ. Press "shift" to get を instead of わ.